# Automatic height of static UITableViewCell with autoLayout not updating in IB (but works when run)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, storyboard

I'm relatively new to Storyboarding and IB, and am a little stuck on this. I have some content (a text view in one cell and a label in another) with autolayout constraints to the cell content view. When I run in simulator, the cells heights are being set correctly based on the contents, but in IB they just have the default height. Is there any way to get IB to reflect what's actually going to happen when running?

Everything for this particular view is in IB (No code in the class file for the TableViewController).

[In IB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83CWS.png)

[In Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjuv4.png)

Comment: I'm no IB expert, but is the issue that IB is a *design* tool and you've set some things in code?

Comment: I have some other classes with custom code (like for that little pull-bar at the bottom in simulator), but I can't see how that would affect this particular view. The TableViewController that contains all of this has no custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very reasonable question, but alas, your expectations are incorrect. IB does positioning / sizing of subviews based on constraints from the superview from the outside in, but it does not do resizing of superviews based on constraints from subviews from the inside out.

Thus, cells can be self-sizing at runtime due to internal constraints, and I take it that yours are. But cell prototypes in a storyboard are *not* self-sizing in the same way. You can *manually* increase the cell height to show more of the contents, and IB will then correctly lay out those contents from the outside in based on that height; but you cannot get a preview of the cell's *automatic* self-sizing from within IB.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Was driving me nuts. Good to know at least.

Comment: Yes, just manually increase the prototype height to accommodate your template content so as to give yourself a _sense_ of what this will look like.